# VisualStudio linked file issue for asp.net core 2.0 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an Asp.net core 2.0 web project. This project references .js files in a class library project.

When I click on a linked file in the project it properly brings me to the library project version of the file.

I added a build event to copy locally all my linked files to the Project (so the javascript files can be included in my wwwroot folder).

```
<Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)" DestinationFiles="%  (Content.Link)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" Condition="'%(Content.Link)' != ''" />
</Target>
```

However, once the files are copied, Visual Studio seems to automatically collect the local version of the files in the solution explorer essentially replacing the linked file. Therefore, if I click on the file to modify it, only the local version is modified and not the linked class library version.

If I delete the local copy, the linked file properly reappears in the solution explorer.

is there a way to tell visual studio to only show the linked files and not their local copy?

Comment: The issue you're having is that the files are not in fact linked. You're just copying the files into your project on build. When you edit, you're editing only this copy. This not the right way to accomplish what you're trying to do. You'll need to confine your edits to your actual class library project.

Comment: @ChrisPratt The files are in fact linked though. There is a 
    <Content Include="..\path\file.js" Link="Path\file.js" /> in the .csproj and they do appear to be linked in the solution explorer. However, when the project is built and the files are copied the link and the copy are both present, but the solution explorer prioritizes the copy instead of the link in it's display

Comment: I'm not clear exactly on what you're talking about, but it's probably just indicating that one comes from the other. The simple fact, though, is that this is not a link. The files are being *copied* into your project, so you're editing the copy only. Edit the source instead, and those edits should then be copied over on build.